# iPad Air - How to type exclamation point from the exclamation/comma key

Tags: ios, keyboard, ipad

This has been bugging me for a while. While I see the exclamation point in the exclamation/comma key, there is no way to make that key type the exclamation point. What I am able to do with the key is to type comma and single quote with the key.

What am I missing? How can I make exclamation/comma key to type exclamation point.

Comment: I don't get your question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Press ⇧,

Press the <kbd>⇧</kbd> shift key, then press the <kbd>,</kbd> comma key, which will insert a `!`.

---

This also works for the question mark above the <kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: Works. Way the keyboard remembers the pressed state of shift key was confusing. If I delete character and backtracks and if shift is active in that state, it will not trigger the exclamation point. I have to turn off shift, and press again for this combo to work.

Comment: And now you should use both hands to type exclamation or question mark, awesome Apple, nice job :D

Comment: Unless you have the split keyboard enabled and the Shift key is not visible. Then there is no way to type "!". You need to disable this in Keyboard settings.